# Return single record from multi join with LINQ in form of viewmodel in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, join, model, viewmodel

I'm trying to return a single record from multi join by LINQ in MVC, I use a model from my personnel database that have main table named personnel, some fields are only an id and dependent on other tables.
Therefore, I need a way to join these tables to retrieve all data, filter them by an id Parameter and put LINQ result to a view model and return it to view.
This is my [Database Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5bcO.png), I used the following code but it doesn't work.

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        var q = from personnel in db.Personels
                join Genders in db.Genders on personnel.GenderId equals Genders.Id
                join nationality in db.Nationalities on personnel.NationalityId equals nationality.Id
                join religion in db.Religions on personnel.ReligionId equals religion.Id
                join course in db.Courses on personnel.CourseId equals course.Id
                join accBank in db.AccBanks on personnel.AccBankId equals accBank.Id
                join advanceStatus in db.AdvanceStatus on personnel.AdvanceStatusId equals advanceStatus.Id
                join chart in db.Charts on personnel.ChartId equals chart.Id
                join contract in db.Contracts on personnel.ContractId equals contract.Id
                join costCenter in db.CostCenters on personnel.CostCenterId equals costCenter.Id
                join job in db.Jobs on personnel.JobId equals job.Id
                join level in db.Levels on personnel.LevelId equals level.Id
                join military in db.Militaries on personnel.MilitaryId equals military.Id
                join subReligion in db.SubReligions on personnel.SubReligionId equals subReligion.Id
                join taxTable in db.TaxTables on personnel.TaxTableId equals taxTable.Id
                join unit in db.Units on personnel.UnitId equals unit.Id
                join workHouse in db.WorkHouses on personnel.WorkHouseId equals workHouse.Id
                join licence in db.Licences on personnel.LicenceId equals licence.Id
                join payPlace in db.PayPlaces on personnel.PayPlaceId equals payPlace.Id
                join married in db.MarriedStatus on personnel.MarriedId equals married.Id
                join jobStatus in db.JobStatus on personnel.JobStatusId equals jobStatus.Id
                where (personnel.Id == id)
                select new PersonnelViewModel()
                {
                    PersonelNo = personnel.PersonelNo,
                    PersonelFName = personnel.PersonelFName,
                    PersonelLName = personnel.PersonelLName,
                    FatherName = personnel.FatherName,
                    NId = personnel.NId,
                    RecognizeNo = personnel.RecognizeNo,
                    BirthDate = personnel.BirthDate,
                    BirthPlace = personnel.BirthPlace,
                    RecordCity = personnel.RecordCity,
                    WorkHouse = workHouse.Name,
                    CostCenter = costCenter.Name,
                    Course = course.Name,
                    Nationality = nationality.Title,
                    Licence = licence.Title,
                    Religion = religion.Title,
                    SubReligion = subReligion.Title,
                    Military = military.Title,
                    Level = level.Title,
                    Chart = chart.Name,
                    Job = job.Name,
                    PayPlace = payPlace.Title,
                    Unit = unit.Name,
                    Contract = contract.Title,
                    Gender = Genders.Title,
                    MarriedStatus = married.Title,
                    ChildQty = personnel.ChildQty,
                    InsNo = personnel.InsNo,
                    Address = personnel.Address,
                    PhoneNumber = personnel.PhoneNumber,
                    MobileNumber = personnel.MobileNumber,
                    Status = personnel.Status,
                    ProcessStatus = personnel.ProcessStatus,
                    JobStatus = jobStatus.title,
                    TaxPerFree = personnel.TaxPerFree,
                    TaxPriceFree = personnel.TaxPriceFree,
                    StartWorkDate = personnel.StartWorkDate,
                    StartRuleDate = personnel.StartRuleDate,
                    EndRuleDate = personnel.EndRuleDate,
                    StopWorkDate = personnel.StopWorkDate,
                    TimeYearlyPrice = personnel.TimeYearlyPrice,
                    DateYearlyPrice = personnel.DateYearlyPrice,
                    TaxMonth = personnel.TaxMonth,
                    AccBankNo = personnel.AccBankNo,
                    AccBank = accBank.Title,
                    SumTimeWork = personnel.SumTimeWork,
                    SumTaxPrice = personnel.SumTaxPrice,
                    SumPay = personnel.SumPay,
                    PrepareStatus = personnel.PrepareStatus,
                    TotalStandWork = personnel.TotalStandWork,
                    InsPerFree = personnel.InsPerFree,
                    InsPriceFree = personnel.InsPriceFree,
                    SumPerWork = personnel.SumPerWork,
                    SumPerWorkTemp = personnel.SumPerWorkTemp,
                    AccCode = personnel.AccCode,
                    PrnFish = personnel.PrnFish
                };
        return View(q);
    }
```

Is there a way?

Comment: Just put your statement in parenthesis and do `.FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: You query is returning a collection. You need to add `.FirstOrDefault()` to the end of it `... PrnFish = personnel.PrnFish}).FirstOrDefault();` (and you were missing the closing `)`

Comment: Thanks I added `.FirstOrDefault()` but it return nothing without error

Comment: Then that means there is nothing that matches your query :)

Comment: Thanks @uteist for your help

Comment: thanks too, @StephenMuecke

Comment: I solved this problem by commented half of joins, I don't understand why I have no result when the number of joins be more than a specefic numbers???

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here. You can use the `Single()` method. This will check the entire collection for a single instance that meets the predicate that you can supply or you can uses the `SingleOrDefault()`. If the collection does not have a instance that meets the predicates requirements then a default value will be returned instead.

The `Single()` and `SingleOrDefault()` methods will throw an exception if more than one record is found that meets the predicate requirement. If that is the case then you can use the `First()` method or the `FirstOrDefault()` method. These methods tend to execute quicker as well as because once an instance is found in your collection no further work is performed to test if any more instances exist.